# RoR4 - has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

i have a little problem with my has_many through: relationship.

The following relationships are given:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord:Base
has_many :group_members
has_many :groups, through: :group_members

Class Group < ActiveRecord:Base
has_many :group_members
has_many :users, through: :group_members

Class GroupMember < ActiveRecord:Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :group
```

If i'm calling

> @groups = User.groups

i am getting a **NoMethodError**. Why? I'm trying to output all members with their groups... how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User class itself does not have a method called groups.

You can have groups for an instance of User, so

```
@user.groups
```

will work.

If you want all the groups then just do

```
Group.all
```

If you want all users and their groups then

```
@users = User.all
```

then you will have to loop through it

```
@users.each do |user|
  groups = user.groups
  # Do something like ...
  puts "#{user.name} has these group"
  puts group.inspect
end
```